# POST request fails while using libcurl, C++

Tags: c++, http, post, libcurl

```
TEST(ApiTest, TestPostMethod) {
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if (curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    std::string url = "https://postman-echo.com/post";
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "https");
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    // curl_slist_append(headers, "HOST:  postman-echo.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    ASSERT_EQ(CURLE_OK, res);
  }
}
```

Error: CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST (6)

When I tested this POST request on postman it worked as expected. Also curl command
`curl --location --request POST 'https://postman-echo.com/post'`
works fine.

```
Expected equality of these values:
  CURLE_OK
    Which is: 0
  res
    Which is: 6
```

Run NSLOOKUP as suggested by @Andreas Wenzel

```
> postman-echo.com
Server:     75.75.75.75
Address:    75.75.75.75#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   postman-echo.com
Address: 3.210.84.203
Name:   postman-echo.com
Address: 52.22.211.29
```

Comment: It works well. Is it a real code? I'm asking cause `CURLOPT_URL` maybe garbage in the real code.

Comment: This is a unit test from my production code. Why `CURLOPT_URL` would garbage?

Comment: For example `std::string url` may be out of `curl_easy_perform` call scope.

Comment: okay. But `std::string` works fine `curl_easy_perform` when a GET request made.

Comment: The documentation on [`CURLOPT_URL`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_URL.html) has a section on the expected "encoding". It says it should normally be ASCII, but under certain conditions, it can also be UTF-8 and the server name can be an "international name". If I am not mistaken, UTF-8 is fully compatible with 7-bit ASCII, so it should not be a problem. However, I am not sure.

Comment: Is my assumption correct that this "unit test" program contains more than what you posted above? If so, then I suspect that some code in your program that you did not post is causing the problem. Maybe that code is causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so that is also affects other parts of your program. Can you reproduce the problem in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: This unit test is quite contained. I edited the post with the complete test code. I think you might be right. Probably this might be happening because server might no have access to the outside network. But when I tried to run this test locally then also I am getting the same error. If there was a problem with other piece of code then it should not give me an error related to host. Host could not be resolved. Correct me if something I am missing. I have a few other ideas. Let me see if I can resolve with those. Would update here I am able to resolve. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: Error code 6 likely means that it was not able to resolve the hostname "postman-echo.com" into an IP address. Therefore, this is likely a DNS issue. You may want to use the command-line tool "nslookup" (which I believe exists on every Linux and Windows operating system) on both hosts in order to determine whether you are able to resolve the host name "postman-echo.com". I believe it must be called with the line "nslookup postman-echo.com".

Comment: I already tried that. Also edited the post for more reference. Also if there was a DNS issue then I should not be able to reach the sever through curl command. 
`curl --location --request POST 'https://postman-echo.com/post'`

Comment: "If there was a problem with other piece of code then it should not give me an error related to host. " - This statement of yours may be incorrect if your test unit did something in a previous test which corrupted memory or something like that (=undefined behavior). Also, if a previous test was calling curl functions which changed default settings or maybe even corrupted the internal state of curl, then this can also be the reason for the strange behavior. Therefore, I really think that you should see if you can reproduce the error in a "minimal reproducible example" (see link above).

Comment: Okay. Will reproduce in a "minimal reproducible example".

Comment: @AnuragAgrawal: Another thing you might want to do is to check the return values of ALL curl functions.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/alexzk1/ed_highway/blob/master/utils/restclient.cpp

this works for many sites last 3-4 years. you can pick those 2 files only.
It uses CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS for post.

Btw, in your code u're following redirects, are u sure website don't redirect you to non-existing link?

Comment: I doubt that a link to sample code will help with the problem the OP is having. However, your idea that the error could be caused by a HTTP redirect is a good idea. Of course, it would have been proper to post this as a comment, not as an answer, because it doesn't answer the question, but is rather a request for further information from the OP. However, I am aware that you don' t yet have sufficient priviledge to post a comment.

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is enabled so if the page is redirected then also it should not be problem. Secondly if the http_request returns a code which 3xx then `curl_easy_perfrom()` would return `CURLE_OK` if everything is goes fine.

Comment: @AnuragAgrawal: I believe the point of the answerer is that the error code 6 could be caused by the DNS lookup of a server other than `postman-echo.com`. Since we don't know if `postman-echo.com` (conditionally) redirects HTTP requests to other servers, we cannot exclude the possiblity that the DNS lookup failed with a server which was the target of a HTTP redirect. For this reason, it may be appropriate to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `0L` for the purposes of a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I figured this out. My server on which I was run this has restrictions in connecting with outside world. Thanks everyone for looking into this.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is strange, though. Why did running curl on the command line work then? Did you run it as a different user with different priviledges?